# How to label zrange in multiplot graph in gnuplot?

Tags: graph, gnuplot

I am plotting multiplot surfaces.
I found this code [1](https://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/05/multiple-layers-on-same-plot.html) very helpful to plot my graph.
However, I want to label the z-axis throughout all surfaces in one plot.
I tried this set zrange[0.5:b+0.5], but nothing showed up. then I tried min_z and max_z, still, nothing showed up.
though I calculated and checked the range by the following the command.

print min_z,max_z.

can anyone please tell me how can I choose zrange with my own choice? like 1 ,2 3 4 5.

Comment: I am bit unsure whether I understand you correctly… are you asking about tic marks along the z axis, i.e. `ztics`?

Comment: Please provide your code and some minimal test data and your resulting graph.

Comment: Are you sure you need multiplot?  The figure you link to could have been made easily without using mutliplot.  And if you have consistent z axis coordinates that also suggests you can position everything in a single plot separated by z.  Perhaps you can show sample codes that demonstrates why/how a single plot doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will expand my comment as a possible answer.  Multiplot is not needed for this style of plot.  Here is an approximate recreation of the figure you linked to.

If you want to customize the axis labels along z, you can add a command to change the format like this: `set ztic format "%.2f"`, and/or add additional commands of the form: `set ztic add ( pi/2 "z = π/2" )`

```
f(x,y,z) =  besj0(x*x/z + y*y/z) / z

set palette cubehelix

set xyplane 0
set view 64,58
set ztics 0.2
unset key

splot for [i=1:6] z=(1.+i/6.), '++' using 1:2:(z):(f(x,y,z)) with pm3d
```

[image]

**Answer expanded to show plotting from a series of files**

Plotting from a series of files is essentially the same. The `splot` command again inserts a constant z value to create a plane, taking the data coordinates [x,y] from columns 1 and 3 and the f(x,y) value from column 4.

Here is an example:

```
set palette defined( 0 "dark-red", 1 "yellow" )

set xyplane 0
set view 74, 62, 0.85, 1.8
set border 16      # z axis only
unset xtics; unset ytics
unset key


file(i) = sprintf("map%d.dat",i)
set ztics ("File 1" 1, "File 2" 2, "File 3" 3, "File 4" 4)

splot for [i=1:4] file(i) using 1:2:(i):3 with image
```

[image]

Comment: HI Ethan, Its so nice of your reply and i can see how i can make the script very small just by passing a for a loop. However, in my case i have data sets consist of three columns  where i am plotting everything using an image command like  *****plot "data.dat" u 1:2:3 with image****

Comment: The commands are basically the same.  I have modified the answer to show plotting from a set of files.